# Getting errors when evaluating TransformedProcess example

Tags: warning-messages, random

I am using the code provided in Mathematica documentation about the in-built *TransformedProcess* function. In the applications (insurance process) one can find the following code:

```
u = 70; c = 61.2; λ = 60; m = 1;
InsuranceProcess = 
  TransformedProcess[u + c t - S[t], S \[Distributed]    
  CompoundPoissonProcess[λ,ExponentialDistribution[1/m]], t];
ListLinePlot[RandomFunction[InsuranceProcess, {0, 100, 0.3}, 15]]
```

When I insert this code into my 10.2 Mathematica, I do not get the plot shown in the documentation, but I get notifications like:

> Parameter 1.`16. at position 3 in *RandomFunction[TransformedProcess*[{70. -1.000000000000000 S[{0, 13.00000000000000}], 865.6 - 1.000000000000000 S[{0, 13.00000000000000}]},S \[Distributed]CompoundPoissonProcess[2.000000000000000, ExponentialDistribution[1.000000000000000]], {0, 13.00000000000000}], {0, 10.00000000000000, 0.01}, 1.000000000000000] *is expected to be a positive integer"*
>
> "*RandomFunction[TransformedProcess*[{70. -1. S[{0.,13.}], 865.6 -1. S[{0., 13.}]}, S[Distributed]CompoundPoissonProcess[2.,  ExponentialDistribution[1.]],{0., 13.}],{0., 10., 0.01}, 1.] *is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers"*

As I am a Mathematica beginner, it seems to me that I must be missing something basic — a basic setting, a line of code that would set the environment correctly.

Is there a package I should unlock or a line I should write down before using these functions?

I have also tried with other applications of `TransformedProcess` and ended up with similar results. If I only use the non-transformed distributions, `RandomFunction` and `ListLinePlot` seem to be functioning normally.

So is there something wrong with my usage of the `RandomFunction`/`TransformedProcess` combination, or is it something else?

Comment: See [How to | Use Brackets and Braces Correctly](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseBracketsAndBracesCorrectly.html) and use your Function without `;` this will give some more Hints. See [CompoundExpression (;)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html)

Comment: You miscopied the code in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedProcess.html), Applications/Insurance Process.  `ExponentialDistribution[1/m]], ` is missing.

Comment: Hi, bbgodfrey, I miscopied the code only to the question. I copied it correctly into the programme. I have edited the question and repaired the code. Thank you for the remark, though.

Comment: And does it still produce the above reported error? Because that error arose due to an invalid (non-integer) third argument to `RandomProcess` (specifying the number of paths to return), which is a trivial error...

Comment: Hi everyone, I tried again and it worked this time. I have no idea what went wrong yesterday, when I tried at least 20-times. I only used automatic copying of the code from the official site both times and comparing yesterdays code to that of today no difference was found. Thank you for all your help. Now I just have to find how to close the question as solved if no answer was given. :D

Comment: Fun fact: the code that produced the error yesterday is working today. Is it possible that it did not work yesterday because of the code sequence that came beforehand? (I also tried in new notebooks yesterday and it did not work, so that cant be the only problem though.)